# Find a linear transfornation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Find a linear transfornation T on $\mathbb R^2$ and closed subset C of $\mathbb R^2$ such that T(C) is not closed.

Please....
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $T(x,y) = x$. It maps the closed set $\{(x,1/x)\ : x \neq 0\}$ to a set which isn't closed.

Comment: Oh.. sorry for my mistake.Find a linear transfornation T on $\mathbb R^2$ and closed subset C of $\mathbb R^2$ such that T(C) is not closed.

Thanks.

Comment: can i use your answer for this new problem? help me please